# How to manually upload my source code to sentry?

Tags: expo, sentry, react-native-sentry

My app is built with expo and sentry dashboard shows me 2 errors :

> Discarded invalid parameter 'type'

and

> Source code was not found for app:///crna-entry.bundle?
>   platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false&assetPlugin=%2FUsers%2FUser%2FDesktop%2Fpath%2Fto%2Fnode_modules%2Fexp.

So when i receive errors, it's impossible to debug because i only have an uglyfied built js.

Is there any way to upload the source expo source code manually. Which file should i send to sentry?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### First way

If you are using expo. You should use `sentry-expo` package which you can find here: [sentry-expo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56162218/5263696)

Put this hook to your **expo json (app.json)** file

```
{
  "expo": {
    "hooks": {
      "postPublish": [
        {
          "file": "sentry-expo/upload-sourcemaps",
          "config": {
            "organization": "<your organization name>",
            "project": "<your project name>",
            "authToken": "<your auth token here>"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
}
```

1. `organization` you can find on here  https://sentry.io/settings/ which named "Organization Name"
2. `project` enter your project name, you can find here:  https://sentry.io/organizations/ORGANIZATION_NAME/projects/
3. `authToken` create a authToken with this url https://sentry.io/api/

Then run `expo publish`, it upload the source maps automatically.

**Testing Locally**

Make sure that you enabled expo development.
add lines;

```
Sentry.enableInExpoDevelopment = true;
Sentry.config(publicDsn, options).install();
```

**As a Result**

On sentry, **for only ios**, you can able to see the source code where error occured.
[image]

**BUT: unable to see the source code for ANDROID**

https://github.com/getsentry/react-native-sentry/issues/372

#### Second way (manual upload)

Using the api https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/sourcemaps/

```
curl -X POST \
  https://sentry.io/api/0/organizations/ORG_NAME/releases/VERSION/files/ \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer AUTH_TOKEN' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F file=@script.min.js.map \
  -F 'name=~/scripts/script.min.js.map'
```